# How to wire TLC59281 to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, 7segmentdisplay

I have a 7 segment display that is driven by a TLC59281. How do I connect its pin to a Raspberry Pi in order to drive the display?

Edit: It uses SPI interface. The datasheet can be found [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59281.pdf).

Comment: What interface does it has?

Answer (score 0):

I found this page very informative as it covers different boards:

One of the images from [learn.adafruit.com](https://learn.adafruit.com/tlc5947-tlc59711-pwm-led-driver-breakout/python-circuitpython):

[image: Pinout]

The pin names of the IC are:

**driver DIN** matches **SIN** in the datasheet

**driver CLK** matches **SCLK** in the datasheet

And the full GPIO of the Pi is this:

[image: Pi]

from: [Raspberry Pi GPIO](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/)